# Segfault in Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

I am getting segmentation fault in the following code.

```
.section .data

myarray:
        .int 10,20,30,40,50,60

format:
        .ascii "%d\n"

.section .text

.globl _start
_start:

movl $2, %ebx
movl myarray(,%ebx,4) , %ecx

pushl %ecx
pushl $format
addl $8,%esp
call printf

movl $1,%eax
movl $0,%ebx
int $0x80
```

While running in gdb, I am getting

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/i386/strchrnul.S:68
68  ../sysdeps/i386/strchrnul.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/i386/strchrnul.S
```

Please point where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addl $8,%esp` removes thing from the stack. It removes the two arguments pushed just above it. This instruction should be after the call to `printf`, not before it.

There could be other errors; I have not checked thoroughly. Also, you have not specified in your question which tools or platform you are using. Different platforms may use different interfaces for calls, interrupts, and system routines.

Comment: Perfect!. I am learning the stack operation needed on esp today, so I missed its location. Thanks for your effort and time. I am using linux and gnu assembler for practice.